# Cannot link with libswscale properly using cmake. Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: sws_getContext()

Tags: cmake, ffmpeg, linker, clang, ld

I'm building a small project that will output video. I'm trying to link to libswscale to convert RGBA to YUV420, however, the linker `ld` cannot successfully find libswscale symbols.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "sws_getContext(int, int, AVPixelFormat, int, int, AVPixelFormat, int, SwsFilter*, SwsFilter*, double const*)", referenced from:
      VideoWriter::writeFrame(std::__1::vector<char, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in video_writer.cpp.o
```

The offending line of code is this.

```
struct SwsContext *sws_ctx = sws_getContext(
    avCodecContext->width, avCodecContext->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA,
    avCodecContext->width, avCodecContext->height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
    SWS_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

When I use -v on clang I see that the libswscale.dylib is being passed to `ld`. The dylib exists on the file system and is the same version as the library's header, as verified by `otool`.

```
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch x86_64 -platform_version macos 10.15.0 11.1 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk -o bin/main -search_paths_first -headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/window.cpp.o CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/video_writer.cpp.o -rpath /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libGLEW.2.2.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.dylib -framework OpenGL /usr/local/Cellar/sdl2_image/2.6.2/lib/libSDL2_image.dylib /usr/local/lib/libSDL2.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libavcodec.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libswscale.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libavutil.dylib -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a -F/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
```

This is my cmake file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19.2)

project(FragTool VERSION 1.0)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

# --- c++ build settings --- #
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Weffc++ -O0")
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

# --- dependencies --- #
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost 1.79.0 COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(LIBAV REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET
    libavcodec
    libswscale
    libavutil
)

pkg_check_modules(LIBSDL2 REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET
    sdl2
    sdl2_image
)

set(EXECUTABLE main)
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE} src/main.cpp)
target_sources(${EXECUTABLE} PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/window.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/video_writer.cpp
)

target_include_directories(${EXECUTABLE} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
target_include_directories(${EXECUTABLE} PRIVATE ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE} PRIVATE GLEW::glew)
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE} PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE} PRIVATE PkgConfig::LIBSDL2)
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE} PRIVATE PkgConfig::LIBAV)
```

I'm stumped as to what could be causing the linker to fail, given that it is being passed the libswscale dylib correctly as far as I can tell. I checked for any other versions of the dylib on the system that maybe are shadowing it, but didn't see any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. It was because the include statement needed to be wrapped with `extern "C"`.

```
extern "C"
{
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}
```